# How to declare an Index state for Vuex modules?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I build large-scale Vue.js project and I using Vuex as my components store. 
The Vuex index file declaring the Vuex modules and have nested modules.

I'm asking how in nested modules I can declare the index module of the nested group.

For now I create in the nested group an index file with the route: 
'moduleGroupName/index'.

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules : {
        'market' : {
            namespaced : true,
            modules : {
                index : Market,
                tripOfferingPopup : TripOfferingPopup,
                filters : MarketFilters,
                trips : Trips,
            }
        },
        'organizer' : {
            namespaced : true,
            modules : {
                index : Organizer,
                market : OrganizerMarket,
            }
        },
        'countrySelect': CountrySelect
...
    },
})
```

My purpose is to get for the market module an index file and not a module with the name index.

something like this:

```
'market' : {
    namespaced : true,
    index : Market,            
    modules : {
        tripOfferingPopup : TripOfferingPopup,
        filters : MarketFilters,
        trips : Trips,
    }
}
```

**My main goal:** 
dispatch a nested module action with the relative path.

For example: 
action in the market index module dispatch trips (a nested module) action like this:

```
fetchData({dispatch }) {
        Axios.get(`/api/market/get-data`)
            .then(response => {
                dispatch('market/trips/init', response.data.trips, {root : true});
            })
```

**without using the root flag.**